# Compiling with the cythonize command throws an error

Tags: python, c++, c, gcc, cpython

I want to try using `cython` following the instructions in the documentation.

I use the command: `cythonize -i test2.pyx` as stated in [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compilation)
file is created `test2.c`, but the file with the extension `.pyd` does not appear next to the original file but instead an error

Error text:

```
ompiling D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Project_Bot_2.7\data\test2.py
 because it changed.
1/1] Cythonizing D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Project_Bot_2.7\data\
est2.pyx
:\miscellanea\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\lib\site-packages\Cython\Com
iler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2
for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: D:\Miscellanea\Programmig
Programming-Python\Project_Bot_2.7\data\test2.pyx
 tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
unning build_ext
uilding 'data.test2' extension
:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\gcc\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -Id:\mis
ellanea\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\include -Id:\miscellanea\programmi
\programming-python\python_2.7\PC -c D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\P
oject_Bot_2.7\data\test2.c -o d:\miscellanea\programmig\programming-python\project_
ot_2.7\data\test2.o
riting d:\miscellanea\programmig\programming-python\project_bot_2.7\data\test2.def
:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\gcc\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s d:\miscellan
a\programmig\programming-python\project_bot_2.7\data\test2.o d:\miscellanea\program
ig\programming-python\project_bot_2.7\data\test2.def -Ld:\miscellanea\programmig\pr
gramming-python\python_2.7\libs -Ld:\miscellanea\programmig\programming-python\pyth
n_2.7\PCbuild -Ld:\miscellanea\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\PC\VS9.0 -l
ython27 -lmsvcr90 -o D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Project_Bot_2.7\d
ta\test2.pyd
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lp
thon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/python27.lib when searching for -lpy
hon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs\libpython27.a when searching for -lp
thon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lp
thon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/python27.lib when searching for -lpy
hon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs\python27.lib when searching for -lpy
hon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lp
thon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/python27.lib when searching for -lpy
hon27
ollect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
rror: command 'D:\\Miscellanea\\Programmig\\Programming-Python\\gcc\\bin\\gcc.exe'
ailed with exit status 1

:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Project_Bot_2.7\data>cythonize -i test2
pyx
ompiling D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Project_Bot_2.7\data\test2.py
 because it changed.
1/1] Cythonizing D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Project_Bot_2.7\data\
est2.pyx
:\miscellanea\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\lib\site-packages\Cython\Com
iler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2
for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: D:\Miscellanea\Programmig
Programming-Python\Project_Bot_2.7\data\test2.pyx
 tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
unning build_ext
uilding 'data.test2' extension
:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\gcc\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -Id:\mis
ellanea\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\include -Id:\miscellanea\programmi
\programming-python\python_2.7\PC -c D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\P
oject_Bot_2.7\data\test2.c -o d:\miscellanea\programmig\programming-python\project_
ot_2.7\data\test2.o
riting d:\miscellanea\programmig\programming-python\project_bot_2.7\data\test2.def
:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\gcc\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s d:\miscellan
a\programmig\programming-python\project_bot_2.7\data\test2.o d:\miscellanea\program
ig\programming-python\project_bot_2.7\data\test2.def -Ld:\miscellanea\programmig\pr
gramming-python\python_2.7\libs -Ld:\miscellanea\programmig\programming-python\pyth
n_2.7\PCbuild -Ld:\miscellanea\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\PC\VS9.0 -l
ython27 -lmsvcr90 -o D:\Miscellanea\Programmig\Programming-Python\Project_Bot_2.7\d
ta\test2.pyd
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lp
thon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/python27.lib when searching for -lpy
hon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs\libpython27.a when searching for -lp
thon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lp
thon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/python27.lib when searching for -lpy
hon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs\python27.lib when searching for -lpy
hon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpython27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/libpython27.a when searching for -lp
thon27
:/miscellanea/programmig/programming-python/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/1
.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible d:\miscellane
\programmig\programming-python\python_2.7\libs/python27.lib when searching for -lpy
hon27
ollect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'D:\\Miscellanea\\Programmig\\Programming-Python\\gcc\\bin\\gcc.exe'
ailed with exit status 1
```

The file itself `text2.pyx`

```
    cdef int su = 0
    cdef int n
    for n in range(10000):
        su += n
    
    return su
```

Comment: You build 32bit but python is 64Bit or other way around.

Comment: how to use 64bit version?